# How is the output determined in these two similar TensorFlow scripts?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Below are two TensorFlow scripts from https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/low_level_intro#training . I am very new to this and attempting to piece together an explanation/understanding; I have listed three questions below the scripts.

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 3])
linear_model = tf.layers.Dense(units=1)
y = linear_model(x)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)

print(sess.run(y, {x: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]}))
```

- I notice that the output contains an array containing two seperate arrays, each containing a single value
- The first value is always between 0 - 6.9999999
- The second value in the second array is between 0 - 15.9999999

---

```
x = tf.constant([[1], [2], [3], [4]], dtype=tf.float32)

y_true = tf.constant([[0], [-1], [-2], [-3]], dtype=tf.float32)

linear_model = tf.layers.Dense(units=1)

y_pred = linear_model(x)

sess = tf.Session()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)

print(sess.run(y_pred))
```

- I notice that the output contains an array containing four seperate arrays, each containing a single value
- The first value is always between 0 - 1.9999999
- The second value in the second array is between 0 - 3.9999999
- The third value in the third array is between 0 - 5.9999999
- The fourth value in the fourth array is between 0 - 6.9999999

---

My questions are:

1. What determines the ranged outputs for both of these respective arrays?
2. Why are the output for both are either all positive or all negative?
3. Why are the output for both have each respective values in numerical order?

Comment: The following is an excerpt from the guide that likely relates to the questions at hand though I dont fully grasp the information: **Layers package together both the variables and the operations that act on them, . For example a densely-connected layer performs a weighted sum across all inputs for each output and applies an optional activation function. The connection weights and biases are managed by the layer object.**

Answer (score 1):

tf.layers.Dense computes  linear combinations of the inputs and applies an activation function on the result.

Since you define units to 1 and don't specify an activation function what you get is ax+by+cz+d in the first example and ax+b in the second example. Actually this is a  column matrix with  rows for performance.

Normally the multipliers (a,b,c,d in the example I offered) are learned. Your code doesn't train them. To learn properly they need to start from some reasonable values (for example 0 is not good for learning). You can specify your own initializer. In this case you use the default (glorot_uniform_initializer according to the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/get_variable)).

You can use `tf.trainable_variables()` to get all the variables (including the ones defined by `tf.layers.Dense` and evaluate them (using `sess.run`) to see their values.

About your questions:

1. What determines the ranged outputs for both of these respective (models?)
   It's a dot product between the inputs you give in x and the random values coming out of the default initializer.
2. Why are the output for both are either all positive or all negative?
   Random chance. Print the variables, run the initializer a few times and see how they change.
3. Why are the output for both have each respective values in numerical order?
   Since you either chanced on the positive weights or the default initializer prefers positive weights the linear combination of higher values will have higher results. In your second example  it should be fairly obvious since you replace 1,2,3,4 in ax+b and a>0.

Comment: In both cases, you get a multipllier for each node/value in the input plus a bias variable. In the first example you have 3 values per example so you get 3 multiplier + bias. In the second you have 1 value per example so you get 1 multiplier + bias. In both cases the initial values are obtained from the initializer (you can specify your own if you want). Normally you would train the model to learn the values for these multipliers/biases.

Comment: Two follow up questions to your explanation: 1) Why do I get **ax+by+cz+d** for the first example AND what would each of those variables (letters) represent? 2) Why do I get **ax+b** for the second example AND what would each of those variables (letters) represent?

Comment: Would you be able to create a single example of how these numbers in each array would be placed within each of **ax+by+cz+d** and **ax+b** ?

Comment: Also, what determines the value of bias?  Are the letters **d** and **b** respectively considered the 'bias'?

Comment: In your first example for `[1, 2, 3]` you basically compute `a*1+b*2+c*3+d`.

Comment: The bias is just another random number obtained from the initializer.  (yes, d, and b are the biases in my examples). Usually in training you learn the right values from them.

Comment: What would a, b, and c represent?  Also random number?  What is the range of this random number?

Comment: They start a random number. Check https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/glorot_uniform_initializer for the range. In training they would be adjusted to the right values.